# Is it possible to disable beep for opening door before shutting off the engine?

Tags: toyota, nissan

I have a Toyota Hybrid Camry with keyless ignition. If open the door (after I park the car) but before I shut off the engine the car will beep at me. This will continue until I get out and close the door. I have no idea what this feature is trying to tell me but it is very annoying.

As a side note I also recently rented a Nissan Maxima and this car does the same thing. Is there an easy way to disable this without pulling out wires?

Comment: I think they're trying to tell you the engine is still running - Though I'd be worried about anyone who didn't notice that! It might be intended more for forthcoming electric cars where you wouldn't have the noise of the engine to remind you it is still on?

Comment: It does this even with an engine stopped.

Comment: Yes the beep will continue long after the engine is stopped. Basically it will keep going until I shut the door. It's very annoying. I've had to retrain myself to make sure I turn off the car before I open the door (yes probably a better habit to be in but annoying for the car to enforce it).

Answer (score 3):

This is by design.

With 'old-style' cars you would physically remove the key from the ignition, so it was quite hard to forget and leave the car running.

With keyless ignition, you could walk away without realising the car is running, especially in a noisy environment.

Car manufacturers don't like being sued, so if there is a chance that drivers could walk away then return to find an empty tank, or even a stolen car, they will make it very obvious to even the dumbest driver that something is not right.

Comment: But why does it continue after I stop the car? The lock button on the door doesn't allow me to lock the door with the keys in the car.

Comment: It is most likely a feature that just gets carried over each year. It is an alert so you don't lock your keys in your car accidentally. mikes makes a good point, it may be a feature that is programmible with your car. If not, you could always take it to Toyota and see if they can do anything for you.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe to inform you that the door is open. It may be that the body control module is seeing an abnormal sequence. The typical sequence being Park,engine off, door open,door close. Since Park, door open, engine off is not typical a bit may be latched triggering the chime. Check the owners manual as it may be programable option. My Impala allows for some personalization of certain functions. Some of the changes I can make are headlight off delay, auto doorlock in drive, keyminder, domelight on after engine shutdown etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your issue but something similar was happening with my RAV4. The door open alarm would sound after parking/shutting off my car. I found setting the headlight switch to off or auto would stop the door open alarm from sounding.  Hope this helps.

Comment: That's probably the 'lights are still on' alarm, meant to make sure you don't forget to switch off the lights so you won't drain the battery...