# Why does my car beep if I open the door and then shutdown the engine?

Tags: toyota, warning-sound

My 2021 Toyota RAV4 has a strange warning beep:

- If I the engine is running and I open the driver door, I don't get a beep
- If I then shutdown the engine, it then starts beeping until I shutdown the door

What is the car trying to warn me about? If its about keeping the doors open after locking the car, there's already a feature where the car starts beeping if you try to lock it while the doors are open. I've tried looking in the manual but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Related (but not duplicate, as my question is about why the feature exists, not about how to turn it off): https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/is-it-possible-to-disable-beep-for-opening-door-before-shutting-off-the-engine

Comment: Usually a warning that you have lights on etc.

Comment: @SolarMike lights are automatically off in my car after 30s

Comment: 30s after engine off? Keys out? Or doors closed? Mine go off after 5 minutes if I leave a door open.

Comment: @SolarMike 30s after engine is off, regardless of whether doors are closed or not

Comment: I'm not sure what "shutdown the door" means but I believe you are hearing the warning about not locking your keys in the car.  Once you shutdown the ignition and open the door, the warning will occur unless you have also removed the key from the ignition.  I know that's what my car does.

Comment: @jwh20 my car is keyless, no ignition per se. It does do a separate beep if you try to lock it with the key inside.

Comment: Kind of an important point don't you think?  Perhaps it's warning you that the FOB is still in the car.  Even though it's not a key, it could still be locked inside.

Comment: @jwh20 Ideally I want to understand Toyota's own internal logic for the beeping. Perhaps its in some obscure technical document?

Comment: There are other threads discussing this problem from earlier models too, such as [Door Chime when Engine is Turned Off](https://www.rav4world.com/threads/door-chime-when-engine-is-turned-off.126594/) and [Make my Rav4 STOP BEEPING AT ME when the driverside doors open and the engine’s off](https://community.cartalk.com/t/make-my-rav4-stop-beeping-at-me-when-the-driverside-doors-open-and-the-engines-off-please/47486). Sadly there are no solutions offered, and the common theme is that it is useless asking the dealer. Is the vehicle in 'Park' mode?

Comment: @WeatherVane its in park mode. I know it cannot be turned off, just looking for Toyota's official explanation for the beeping.

Comment: Having driven many vehicles (worked at an oil change shop so was always in a different vehicle), the only thing I can conclude is that the manufacturer wanted the vehicle to constantly scream "I am a toyota". Seatbelts, doors open, key in, key out, anything you do, the vehicle tends to feel obligated to remind you that it is, indeed, manufactured by toyota. I've come very close to ripping the beeper out of my own vehicle for my own sanity

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a warning to help you avoid locking your keys in the car. Keyless entry systems can generally tell whether the keyfob is inside or outside the car, and the car is probably checking multiple sensors (fob inside vs outside, doors open vs closed, ignition on vs off, and deciding that the current conditions could lead to you locking your keys in the car.

I most often see this happen when two people with keyfobs are in the car at the same time and one person exits the car while the other stays inside.